# all if statements are executed c++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am making a program that lets the user insert a grade, and the program will display a message based on that grade.

For some reason the if-statements are all being executed, and I dont know why that happens.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 string ques;
cout << "Hello would you like to insert a letter grade or a number grade?\n";
cin >> ques;

    if (ques=="letter")
    {
        char grade;
        cout <<"Enter your grade: ";
        cin >> grade;

        switch (grade)
        {
            case 'F' :
                cout << "You should start revising!"<<endl;
                break;
            case 'D':
                cout <<"You can do better!"<<endl;
                break;
            case 'C':
                cout<<"Improvement is possible!"<<endl;
                break;
            case 'B':
                cout <<"You`re getting there , keep it up!"<<endl;
                break;
            case 'A':
                cout <<"Congratulations! See?? Your hard work payed off!"<<endl;
                break;
        }
    return 0;

    }
    else
    {
        int nrGrade;
        cout <<"Enter your grade: ";
        cin >> nrGrade;

        if (nrGrade >=0 && nrGrade <= 59)
        {
            cout <<"Your grade is an F. You should start revising!"<<endl;
        }
        else (nrGrade >= 60 && nrGrade <= 69);
        {
        cout <<"Your grade is a D. I`m sure you can do better!"<<endl;
        }
        if (nrGrade >= 70 && nrGrade <=79)
        {
        cout <<"Your grade is a C. I`m sure you can improve!"<<endl;
        }
        else (nrGrade >= 80 && nrGrade <=89);
        {
        cout <<"Your grade is a B. You`re getting there , keep it up!"<<endl;
        }
        if (nrGrade >= 90 && nrGrade <= 100)
        {
            cout <<"Your grade is an A. Congratulations for your grade! Keep it up!"<<endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I am using codeblocks, because I have some issues with visual studio. Anyone has a clue why this is happening?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Your `else` branches consist of a condition. After the `else` branches you got a block which is unconditionally executed. You *probably* wanted to write `else if (...) { ... }` (note that there is no semicolon between the closing parenthesis and the opening brace).

Comment: Strange, I would expect a modern C++ compiler to emit warning about those boolean expressions with no effect, but I can't get any (on the few online g++ sites I tried), even with -Wall -Wextra -pedantic ...

Answer (score 3):

```
if (nrGrade >=0 && nrGrade <= 59)
{
    cout <<"Your grade is an F. You should start revising!"<<endl;
}
else (nrGrade >= 60 && nrGrade <= 69);
{
    cout <<"Your grade is a D. I`m sure you can do better!"<<endl;
}
```

Here the part `(nrGrade >= 60 && nrGrade <= 69);` is considered as an instruction for the else-statement because of the trailing `;`, and because `else` does not take a condition as argument. Remember the syntax of the [if-statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) is:

```
if( condition )
    statement-true
else
    statement-false
```

While you tried to write:

```
if( condition1 )
    statement-true
else( condition2 );
    statement-false
```

The following block with `cout` is then executed because it is unrelated to your if/else.

In fact, your code is equivalent to:

```
if (nrGrade >=0 && nrGrade <= 59)
{
    cout <<"Your grade is an F. You should start revising!"<<endl;
}
else
{
    nrGrade >= 60 && nrGrade <= 69;
}
cout <<"Your grade is a D. I`m sure you can do better!"<<endl;
```

I think the logic you want is more:

```
if (nrGrade >=0 && nrGrade <= 59)
{
    cout <<"Your grade is an F. You should start revising!"<<endl;
}
else
{
    if (nrGrade >= 60 && nrGrade <= 69)
    {
        cout <<"Your grade is a D. I`m sure you can do better!"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Which can be written:

```
if (nrGrade >=0 && nrGrade <= 59)
{
    cout <<"Your grade is an F. You should start revising!"<<endl;
}
else if (nrGrade >= 60 && nrGrade <= 69)
{
    cout <<"Your grade is a D. I`m sure you can do better!"<<endl;
}
```

Here the second `if` is used as statement for the `else`, forming the pseudo-keyword `else if` with the following syntax:

```
if( condition1 )
    statement1
else if( condition2 )
    statement2
else
    default-statement
```

---

By the way, when both if- and else-blocks end with the same instruction, you may want to extract it. In other words:

```
int main()
{
    // ...

    if (ques=="letter")
    {
        // ...
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
        return 0;
    }
}
```

should be:

```
int main()
{
    // ...

    if (ques=="letter")
    {
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "In fact, your code is equivalent to: ... `else {  nrGrade >= 60 && nrGrade <= 69; }`" I find that confusing. Why did you put the condition inside the body of the else ?

Comment: Because as it was written, that was not a condition. The keyword `else` does not take a condition as argument. Here, because of the trailing `;`, the code between parentheses was considered as the instruction of the `else`, and I put this instruction in an instruction block to make it more visible

Comment: ah yes sorry, my mistake. You are completely right :). I confused it with a `else if`

Comment: it worked when I`ve done this if (nrGrade >=0 && nrGrade <= 59)
{
    cout <<"Your grade is an F. You should start revising!"<<endl;
}
else
{
    if (nrGrade >= 60 && nrGrade <= 69)
    {
        cout <<"Your grade is a D. I`m sure you can do better!"<<endl;
    }
} , and I have no clue WHY... when i tried this if (nrGrade >=0 && nrGrade <= 59)
{
    cout <<"Your grade is an F. You should start revising!"<<endl;
}
else if (nrGrade >= 60 && nrGrade <= 69)
{
    cout <<"Your grade is a D. I`m sure you can do better!"<<endl;
} , it said it was wrong , aren`t they the same thing??

Comment: You can't indent code in comments, and it's hard to read without indentation. Please edit your question by adding your new code, the error log if there is a compile error or what you get as output when running the code otherwise

Comment: I didn't say "modify your question", I said "add to your question". Never ever remove your original question in SO since that makes the answers completely unrelated to the question. I rolled back your edit. If consider your problem is not fixed, edit your question, but **add** a new paragraph and **do not** remove the original text. If you consider your problem is fixed and have a new one, ask a new question in a new post

Comment: I didn`t remove the original question.. I added an "edit" at the bottom of it .....

Comment: You modified the original code and removed your initial errors: that's modifying the original question...

Answer (score 0):

Wrong if-else implementation.

It should be

```
if(condition1) {
    //do something
}
else if (condition2) {
    //do something else
}
else
{
    //do other stuff
}
```

For example:

```
if (nrGrade >=0 && nrGrade < 60)
{...
}
else if (nrGrade >= 60 && nrGrade < 70)
{...
}
else if (nrGrade >= 70 && nrGrade < 80)
{...
}
else if (nrGrade >= 80 && nrGrade < 90)
{...
}
else if (nrGrade >= 90 && nrGrade <= 100)
{...
}
else
{
cout << "ERROR"
}
```

Else does not require an input, so the comparison you are writing, followed by a ';', is considered as an instruction.

Best

Comment: I get an error if i do this.. it says "else" without a previous "if"

Comment: Could you please post a snap of your modified code?